# UC4 Appworx V8 - Send spool file in attachment

Tags: unix

I got a Korn Shell that calls a SQL/PLUS to check and spool data into a .CSV file in UNIX.

This KShell is working fine on Unix, it creates the file and Return 0.

Launching the Job from UC4 AppWorx i want him to Attach the Spooled File in UNIX in the Notification sended by the Job when he Finish.

I want this to work this way:

1º I Launch the Job

2º It checks the data, if data is founded then it creates a file in /tmp directory in UNIX with the .CSV extension.

3º When the job finishes he send me an email with Spool File (.CSV) in Unix.

Is there any way? How can i make this?

Thanks.

Comment: For the love of god, someone create an Appworx tag already.

Comment: It requires 1500 rep :(

Comment: I'm only at 992... I've been trying to get enough to create it now for over a year. Hopefully someone will see the comment and do an edit for us.

Comment: Hey i managed to do this using UC4 Conditions to check the data in the table (using UC4 Variable with Select Decode) if retrieves Y RunS Task otherwise Skip Task. But im facing a problem now... how do i spool 2 files in one notification ^^ im using spool &1 to create one single spool in the UC4 Notification.. i triue spool &1 for the 1st query and spool 2& for the 2nd query.. but not working... :( im trying to do this with one single job.

Comment: If the files are both in /tmp and named similarly, you can have the "pattern" email attachment grab both (assuming they can both be selected with the correct glob/wildcard). But that depends on your naming convention, whether you can tell yesterday's files from today's, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an chain in Appworx (the docs should be able to walk you through it). This chain will have 1 or more jobs.

First, you don't need a k script to call SQL/PLUS. You can invoke SQL/PLUS directly. Write the script as a .sql file (it can include sqlplus directives, sql, and PL/SQL as needed). Set the job as "program type" AWSQLP. Point it at the .sql script that you have made available to Appworx.

The sqlplus script can use logic to determine if it should create a file. If it should, it can write out files directly (though getting proper .csv files from it can be a pain).

Then, attach a notification to the job, and the notification object should be set to do an email attachment. You'll have to use the "pattern" type, and put in a full filepath to the csv. Substitution variables can be used if you want a new filename each invocation.

Depending on your version, some of these options can be moved around a bit (We just upgraded last year, UC4 no longer owns it). Click on the help menu and do to the documentation entry... it's not the best in the world, but far from the worst.

Comment: Sorry @John O im new here so i answered you instead of commenting. Can you check what i said please.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for answering.

I usually create a JOB lets say, SEM_CHECK_THINGS, with 1 prompt defined on UC4 that runs a Query in the Database to check if the table, test_table (Example) got data, to do this i use **select decode(count(*),0, 'N', 'Y') from test_table;**

This job also executes a simple KShell in unix:

KShell Content:

```
echo "Job Name: $1"
echo "Job Control Flag: $2"

jobName=$1
jobFlag=$2

echo "Job ${jobName} started ..." >> $logFile
date >> $logFile

if [[ ${jobFlag} == "Y" ]]; then
    echo "Job ${jobName} executed successfully with data found." >> $logFile
    echo "Job ${jobName} executed successfully with data found."
    exit 1
else
    echo "Job ${jobName} finished with no data found." >> $logFile
    echo "Job ${jobName} finished with no data found."
    exit 0
fi
```

I usually force "ABORT" by using Exit 1 if data is found to request another Job that will execute an .SQL that will spool the data from the test_table.

```
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
whenever sqlerror exit 1
prompt this is a test
set echo off
set trimspool on
set trimout off
set linesize 1500
set feedback on
set newpage none
SET HEADING OFF
set und off
set pagesize 10000
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-MON-yyyy HH24:MI:SS';
spool &1
SELECT 'PREV_RESULTSET;LAST_RESULTSET;NR_COUNT' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT PREV_RESULTSET||';'||LAST_RESULTSET||';'||COUNT(1) NR_COUNT
            FROM SEM_REPORT_PEDIDOS
     GROUP BY PREV_RESULTSET, LAST_RESULTSET;
spool off
exit 1
```

By using the Spool &1 and by "Hardcoding" the file testspool.csv in the "Other Output" option in the Notification of that Job i managed to do this, to receive an email with the content i need/want from that table.

But i want really want its to make this in one single job, make a validation, if data is found then Spool and attach .CSV file to the email notification sent by that job.